# moving from Meta to Beta

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, questions

It seems easy to go from Beta to Meta. But I'm wasting a lot of time to find an easy way to return to Beta.

Would it be possible to have a button that allows fast return to Beta (or what it will be in future)?

Comment: I had the same frustration and just recently figured this out so thanks for asking this!

Comment: @JNat why was status-completed added?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The fastest way I know if is to click on the "three part bubble" on the very top right of the Meta page, which opens a drop down menu, then click "Bioacoustics" on the top row and you'll be taken back to the main page.

[image: Screenshot showing how to access the menu to take you back to the main Bioacoustics Beta site from within Meta]

Answer (score 1):

If you're into keyboard shortcuts, here's how you can use 'em:

> You can switch to the meta site (and vice versa) with *no* clicks at
> all, using keyboard shortcuts:
>
> 1. From your profile [settings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/current),
>    enable keyboard shortcuts.
> 2. From anywhere on the site, you can easily go to the meta site (and vice versa) using <kbd>G</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>.
>
> Here's a demonstration of this method on Super User:
>
> [image]

(From my answer to [Could we go to the meta sites more quickly?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/343876/could-we-go-to-the-meta-sites-more-quickly) on Meta Stack Exchange)